# How to redirect specific page to another url on nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am using matomo hosted on this sample url:

> https://testmatomo.azureapp.com

Since I want to secure the admin page of matomo, I setup a Cloudflare Access w/ Zero Trust for that specific domain hosted on this:

> https://testmatomo.companyname.com

When I access directly the CF link it is working properly. However when I try to access the original link, the login admin page can still be accessed. How can I redirect requests coming from https://testmatomo.azureapp.com/index.php (all admin pages are starting in this /index.php***) into https://testmatomo.companyname.com

EDIT:

Only the admin page which resides on

> https://testmatomo.azureapp.com/index.php

should be redirected to new url. Since we are doing browser tracking, all requests should still be directed on to old url.

Here is my current conf:

```
  server {
  server_name testmatomo.azureapp.com;
  root /var/www/matomo/;
  index index.php;

  location ~ ^/(index|matomo|piwik|js/index).php {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }
  
  location = /plugins/HeatmapSessionRecording/configs.php {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
    deny all;
    return 403;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ /(config|tmp|core|lang) {
    deny all;
    return 403;
  }

  location ~ \.(gif|ico|jpg|png|svg|js|css|htm|html|mp3|mp4|wav|ogg|avi|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|json)>
    allow all;
  }

  location ~ /(libs|vendor|plugins|misc/user) {
    deny all;
    return 403;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, pick one that applies best to your situation. Edit your nginx config file and add the necessary info to it.

```
server {
# Temporary redirect to an individual page
rewrite ^/old-url$ http://www.example.com/new-url redirect;
}

server {
# Permanent redirect to an individual page
rewrite ^/old-url$ http://www.example.com/new-url permanent;
}

server {
# Permanent redirect to non-www
server_name www.example.com;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
# Permanent redirect to www
server_name example.com;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
# Permanent redirect to new URL
server_name example1.com;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://example2.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

This last one should probably do for your case.
Then check your config and restart nginx:

```
$ nginx -t
$ systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: Wont this affect other requests intended for the old URL?

Comment: I had to re-read your original request... This would do the redirect for everything testmatomo.azureapp.com indeed. 
Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037716/how-to-redirect-single-url-in-nginx for single page redirection

Comment: I've tried the answers for that link however I'm stuck with too many redirect error